# How do I edit an image in Photoshop so it looks like it was hand-painted like this?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, image-editing

[image]

Does anyone have any idea about how to edit like this in Photoshop? I have used Google to search for this, but have found nothing.

Comment: The Oil Paint filter.

Comment: To try and deconstruct how this was done, it's always help to start with [the same source image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/GI811.jpg) and try to recreare it. Google's reverse image search is handy for that

Answer (score 5):

Select the filter Menu -> Oil paint…, and use the following settings as shown in the image below to get this effect. Adjust your own settings according to your picture.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

In your sample hairs looks like painted over with tiny brush and tablet. Not a filter. Not sure that such effect can be achived just with a filter.